# Sending data value to input

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wrote a function that gets me the child's value. I'm using the function with the button. I want the value to be put in, for example, the input so that I can send it to firebase.

This is the function that gets the value of the child element and places it in the element with the id **hour**. I tried with `textarea`. Displayed the value but when adding `formControlName="hour"` has stopped working. I am asking for help with this case

```
 getHour() {
  const child = document.getElementsByClassName('day picked')[0];
      const value = child.children[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
      document.getElementById('hour').innerHTML = value;
      console.log(value);
  }
```

this is textarea, which stop working after adding formControlName = "hour".

```
    <textarea id= 'hour' readonly=readonly  formControlName="hour"></textarea>
```

Comment: change the id or `formControlName`. both are same there, maybe it's the reason

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not it. I changed the textarea to p and sent it. The firebase showed "hour" but the value is empty

Answer (score 0):

few suggestions:

First I dont know if your actually using the command in the right manner.
getElementByClassNames('class1 class2') is actually searching for element that has both this classes attached to them!.

Maybe a better approach would be using querySelector.
In addition, it may help you choose the children elements easier aswell.

Example:

```
Const value = querySelector('.class').value;
querySelector('.class2:first-child').innerHTML = value;
```

PS. Istead of innerHTML use textContent.

Comment: The problem is that when the value is placed eg in the p tag it is displayed. When I send it, an empty value comes. When he writes manually, the value appears in Firebase